# Value Expression for CoreData simple migration of NSDate and empty NSStrings?

Tags: ios, core-data

I added some new NSDate attributes to my model and I have no idea what to put in the Value Expression column for my mapping model.

Same goes for a few new string attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just leave that column empty. The values will be set to NULL when the model migration occurs.

Comment: Thanks, so I added my mapping model and left everything empty and the migration does not happen - how would I track down what is causing this?

Comment: You need to provide the following options when opening the store: `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption]`.

Comment: I have that and have migrated from other model versions without issue before which I why i am so confused that it is not working this time.

Comment: Yes, can't find model for store.  But I think I am just going to delete my store and have it recreated, it holds a bunch of information stored remotely and it needs to be updated anyways with some new data.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NicolasBachschmidt Is there any way you can share a screenshot? I'm trying to nullify an existing relationship by setting the value expression to "" (empty string) under Relationship mappings in the xcmapping model but I get a migration error